# Site logo link to root Site Collection using powershell

Tags: powershell, site-collection, site-logo

I'm searching for a PowerShell script to link/redirect all the logos of the sites to site collection root.

I know that I can code in master page file, like this solution (http://samanalie.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/site-logo-link-to-root-site-collection-in-sharepoint-2013/) but can I do it better, using PowerShell?

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You only need to run one line of PowerShell to set all the site logos on SharePoint sites in a site collection (much easier than setting them by hand).

```
(Get-SPSite http://SiteCollectionUrl).AllWebs | foreach {$_.SiteLogoUrl = "the path of your logo.gif"; $_.Update()}
```

Comment: It did not work for me. The code executed properly. But subsite is still going to its homepage instead of root site's homepage.